# Hibernate one to one mapping with Static table

Tags: java, hibernate

According to my requirement, I have a Rate Master table where some criteria wise rate is defined. This is static table and does not change on transaction basis.Now whenever user register to the system they subscribe for a specific plan(Rate) and in subscription table we store the user details along with with rate wise subscription they have chosen.

```
**Table Details:**
**Rate Master Table -** 
rate_id- INT -Auto generated.
Amount - INT

**Subscription table -** 
ID - INT -Auto generated.
User_ID - VARCHAR - USER ID (No relation with user table)
Rate_Id - INT - RATE MASTER table ID (Though this only hibernate will fetch all the records of Rate)
```

Now please help me how this mapping should be done on Hibernate POJO side. For individual table wise pojo everything is working as expected but when I am doing relationship in Subscription pojo, system forcing me to mark insertable=false,updatable=false. So, please help me with the Subscription table POJO and process to do it without updating rate table in every subscription update.
Note: This relation will be uni-directional subscription table to rate mapping only.

```
@Column(name = "rate_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private int rateId;
@OneToOne(targetEntity = RateMaster.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "rate_id", referencedColumnName = "rate_id")
private RateMaster rateMaster;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate insists on `insertable=false,updatable=false` because the `rateId` field is mapped to the same column that is used as a join column for the relationship with the `RateMaster` entity.  You have thus introduced a redundancy, and Hibernate cannot promise to preserve any inconsistent data you introduce through that redundancy.

My recommendation would be to just ditch the `rateId` field altogether.  Manage the underlying column via the `RateMaster` entity assigned to each `Subscription`.  If necessary, introduce a read-only, non-persistent accessor on `Subscription` that provides the `rateId` by obtaining it from the `RateMaster`.

Comment: if I ditch rateId field altogether then what would be the mapping for RateMaster in SUbscription.java.

Secondly, as said that RateMaster would be read only. That means Subscription table will be updated but RateMaster will remain constant.

Comment: No, @Souvik.  Do not ditch the `rate_id` *column*.  Ditch only the `rateId` field in your entity class.  The column is already mapped via the entity relationship.  That's the whole nature of the redundancy I'm talking about.

Comment: If you don't want `RateMaster`s to be modified, then simply avoid providing property setters on that class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I am able to fetch SubscriptionDetails with RateDetails. But I am bit confused on the Insertion. Due to some other business logic I can not remove the setter from RateMaster. So, how can I handle the issue where RateMaster table will not be updated in the system and only Subscription Table will. Also note that the Subscription table contains the RateId for mapping. So, need to save the same also.

Comment: For relation now I am using OneToOne & PrimaryKeyJoinColumn